# React Hooks - Start search when I click on Enter

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the following example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [userQuery, setUserQuery] = useState('');

  const searchUserQuery = (e) => {
    window.open(`http://google.com/search?q=${userQuery}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <div className='form'>
        <input
          type='text'
          value={userQuery}
          onChange={(e) => setUserQuery(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={searchUserQuery}>Google Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Once I click on the Button, a new browser tab opens with Google and shows the search result.

However, it works only if I click the button. If I write something in the input and hit the **Enter key** on my keyboard, nothing happens.

Isn't it that in a form pressing the Enter key should trigger the form?
How could I modify my code, so that pressing the Enter key, starts the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `form` element and `onSubmit` event. Here's what you'll go with:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [userQuery, setUserQuery] = useState('');

  const searchUserQuery = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    window.open(`http://google.com/search?q=${userQuery}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <form className='form' onSubmit={searchUserQuery}>
        <input
          type='text'
          value={userQuery}
          onChange={(e) => setUserQuery(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Google Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank mate. Of course, I had forgotten to use a form element! Once I changed the wrapper from div to a form, I didn't even need to use onSubmit and it works.

Comment: Yeah, that might work as well as far as you have submit button and action in it. But it's good to use onSubmit event and you don't need to bind event in button.